# Route all pages After Index Page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I Use simple configuration in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It help me to remove .php from pages now i want to get all pages after index like this is my index page https://www.example.com/index if i point to about page it should move after index like this https://www.example.com/index/about also my about page is in same directory 
kindly Help !

Thanks

Comment: So `https://www.example.com/index/about` should be handled by `https://www.example.com/index.php/about` ?

Comment: yes i want something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.*)?/?$ /$1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: i try this but it's not point to about page i point url like this https://www.example.com/index.php/about but its on index page still

Comment: THis rule does exactly as I commented above. It will internally load content of `https://www.example.com/index.php/about`. If that is not what you need clearly write what URI should be loaded?